# Authorize.net CIM - How to delete a customer profile from Authorize.net CIM

Tags: authorize.net

In my project i am creating  customer profile (Not a payment profile) in Authorize.net (CIM) for each user registration, i have successfully implemented that. but i have to delete these customer profiles (Not a payment profile) dynamically i.e when Site admin deleting each user from this project, have to delete customer profile from Authorize.net merchant account.

Please anyone help me!!!!

Answer (score 2):

As per the [Authorize.Net CIM XML Guide](http://www.authorize.net/support/CIM_XML_guide.pdf) use the deleteCustomerProfileResponse API call on page 57:

> This function is used to delete an
>   existing customer profile along with
>   all associated customer payment
>   profiles and customer shipping
>   addresses.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<deleteCustomerProfileRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
  <merchantAuthentication>
    <name>YourUserLogin</name>
    <transactionKey>YourTranKey</transactionKey>
  </merchantAuthentication>
  <customerProfileId>10000</customerProfileId>
</deleteCustomerProfileRequest>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..,how can i get "customerProfileId", becuase i am creating customer profile, i am passing only MerchantCustomerId at the time of creating a profile. I have checked this profiles in Authorize.net CIM account, there is two ID for each profile, accountID (MerchantCustomerId) and profileID, i am passing only the MerchantCustomerId, so how can i get the profileID dynamically?

Comment: The profile ID is returned when the profile is created. You need to store it in a database so you can retrieve it and use it when making future API calls for that user.

Answer (score 0):

Well there must be a function that will delete the Customer Profile ID  But If you want to delete customer payment Profile then use this method in C#

```
  public string DeleteCustPmtProfId(Int64 custProfID, Int64 custPmtProfID)
 {
  CustomerProfileWS.DeleteCustomerPaymentProfileResponseType response = SoapAPIUtilities.Service.DeleteCustomerPaymentProfile(SoapAPIUtilities.MerchantAuthentication, custProfID, custPmtProfID);
  for (int i = 0; i < response.messages.Length; i++)
     {
        lblStatus.Text = lblStatus.Text + "<br/>Message: " + response.messages[i].text + "<br/>Response Code: " + response.resultCode + "<br/>"; 
      }     

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting customer profile can delete all the associated payment profile and shipping address profile as well. You can use the following, this will definitely works.

```
$xml = new AuthnetXML(AUTHNET_LOGIN, AUTHNET_TRANSKEY, AuthnetXML::USE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER);
$xml->deleteCustomerProfileRequest(array(
    'customerProfileId' => '5427896'
));
```

Originally Referenced from: https://github.com/stymiee/Authorize.Net-XML/blob/master/examples/cim/deleteCustomerProfileRequest.php

Comment: You should mention this requires the [AuthnetXML library](https://github.com/stymiee/Authorize.Net-XML) and provide where to get it. Otherwise users will have no idea why this doesn't work for them. Also, you are assuming they are using PHP. They do not indicate they are using PHP.